# How to shift iframe towards right side?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm currently working on the feature in which whenever a user hovers over a link, instant preview is shown below the link. Like this -

[image]

What I wanted to do is, whenever a user hovers over a link, iframe should shift towards right, just like in **Google Instant preview**.

```
<div class="title" (mouseover)="overTitle()" (mouseleave)="overTitle()">
                    <a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                    <div class="box">
                        <iframe width="400px" height="400px" [src]="myUrlList[i]"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS file -

```
 .box {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
    }

    a:hover + .box, .box:hover{
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index:100;
    }
```

I tried using `align="right"` in div tag, but nothing happens. Also in .box class in CSS, I tried using `float: right;`, but nothing happens. It will be very much helpful if someone can help me. :)

Comment: If you're absolutely positioning, float won't help. Maybe try right:0?

Comment: @RachelS Thanks for giving time to my question :) . 'Maybe try right' with which property?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check something like that, without JS, pure CSS.
https://jsfiddle.net/fxdhcrxj/2/

I just use opacity and visibilityto animate fade in and out, you can use any other methods, like JS fade In out etc.

In CSS if you want catch next element use `~`

**CSS:**

```
.title{
    // for proper position absolute element inside
    position: relative;
}

// We catch nexy element .box, and when some one hover over box
.title a:hover ~.box, .title .box:hover{
    //display: inline;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
// As i use element to bottom 0, I must translated it 100% below of his height.
.title .box{
    //display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="title" >
    <a href="#">TITL0E</a>
    <div class="box">
        <iframe width="400px" height="400px" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Important Note:**

If you want put lot of Iframes, on page use Lazy load on them.
Simply just replace src attr when someone hover over title or use scripts e.g
http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/ otherwise your page will load really slow and make lot of freezes etc.

For better mobile support you may also use `focus` on element, not only hover

Comment: Thanks for giving time to my question. :) Yeah page loads very slowly and makes lot of freezes too. Solution will be helpful. But the question was, I want to shift the iframe towards right side. The jsfiddle which you have given - the preview must be shown to right side (just like google instant preview) when mouse hovers on link rather showing towards downside. What should I do according to my code?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, you may use something like https://jsfiddle.net/fxdhcrxj/3/
or like https://jsfiddle.net/fxdhcrxj/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/vxVoKd

```
a:hover + .box, .box:hover {
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      z-index:100;
    }
```

You need to have `right:0;` set for the box. Also, your .box was set for a 100% width which is why the iframe didn't know where to go. You have to options: Either set the box width to 400px, which is the same as the iframe (which is what I did in my codepen):

```
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
}
```

OR you may leave the 100% width but then add `text-align:right;` to the .box class. Both work.

```
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```